# Push notification sandbox stopped Working

Tags: ios, push, sandbox

With no code changes, notifications are not received on device. I already tried to revoke all the certificates and recreate them. Payload is sent successfully but not displayed on my iPhone.

I already checked that notifications are activated on the phone.

Than you for your help

Comment: I'm having the same issue.

Comment: Omg, I was thinking that I'm have error somewhere...

Comment: It started somewhat 10hours ago. I thought it's going to be some short down time. But still not working.

Comment: Nothing is displayed on https://developer.apple.com/system-status/ :/

Comment: What libraries/frameworks are you using the send APNS?

Comment: No frameworks. I'm just using Knuff to send a push notification.

Comment: I've posted a thread at https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/86282

Comment: same issue here.... I thought I was getting crazy.